# ”Correct” way to debug print custom classes in Swift

Tags: swift, debugging

For custom classes implementing custom debug description like the following one:

```
struct SCFile: CustomDebugStringConvertible {

    let path: String
    let status: SCFileStatus

    var debugDescription: String {
        return "<SCFile path:\(path), status:\(status)>"
    }
}
```

What's the ”correct” way to debug print a custom class in Swift?

Like this?

```
<SCFile path:/path/file.stuff, status:Modified>
```

Or like this?

```
SCFile(path: "/path/file.stuff", status: SCFileStatus.Modified)
```

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a "correct" way but the second seems closer to what Swift does.

An example:

var str = "Hello, playground"
let range = (Range(start: str.startIndex, end: str.endIndex))
print(range.debugDescription)

Prints:

> Range(0..<17)